# Sending text message to the web C# service in Android

Tags: android

I want to send Android's inbox messages to the web C# service, but I am getting this error `attempt to invoke virtual method  ' int java.lang.String.length()' on a null object reference`. What could be the reason? Kindly help me resolve this. Have a good day.
Below is the code I am using:

```
private final String NAMESPACE3 = "http://tosman/";
private final String METHOD_NAME3 = "gelenkutusu";
private final String SOAP_ACTION3 = "http://tosman/gelenkutusu";
private final String URL3 = "http://takiprogrami-001-site1.smarterasp.net/Service1.asmx";
Uri uriSMSURI = Uri.parse("content://sms/inbox");
cur = getContentResolver().query(uriSMSURI, null, null, null,null);

String sms = "";
long tim;
if(cur.moveToFirst()) {
    for(int i=0; i < cur.getCount(); i++) {
        String date = cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex(Sms.DATE));
        Long timestamp = Long.parseLong(date);
        SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy/HH:mm");
        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        calendar.setTimeInMillis(timestamp);
        String finaldate = dateFormat.format(calendar.getTime());
        smsDate = finaldate.toString();
        InboxSmsBody=(cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndexOrThrow(Sms.BODY)).toString());
        InboxSmsFrom=(cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndexOrThrow(Sms.ADDRESS)).toString());
        InboxSmsDate=smsDate;
        Log.e("BODY", InboxSmsBody);
        new ToastMessageTask().execute(InboxSmsFrom, InboxSmsBody,smsDate);
        // new ToastMessageTask().execute("");
        cur.moveToNext();
    }
}
cur.close();
private void inbox(String from, String body,String date) {
    SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE3, METHOD_NAME3);
    PropertyInfo DateInfo = new PropertyInfo();
    DateInfo.setName("from");
    DateInfo.setValue(from);
    PropertyInfo BodyInfo = new PropertyInfo();
    BodyInfo.setName("body");
    BodyInfo.setValue(body);
    PropertyInfo FromInfo = new PropertyInfo();
    BodyInfo.setName("date");
    BodyInfo.setValue(date);
    request.addProperty(FromInfo);
    request.addProperty(BodyInfo);
    request.addProperty(DateInfo);
    SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(
            SoapEnvelope.VER11);
    envelope.dotNet = true;
    envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);
    HttpTransportSE httpTransportSE = new HttpTransportSE(URL3);
    try {

        httpTransportSE.call(SOAP_ACTION3, envelope);
        SoapPrimitive soapPrimitive = (SoapPrimitive) envelope
                .getResponse();
        inboxsmsResult = soapPrimitive.toString();
        Log.e("inboxsmsResult=", inboxsmsResult);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("inboxsmsResult", e.getMessage());
    }
}
private class ToastMessageTask extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {
    public String inboxsmsdate;
    public String inboxsmsfrom;
    public String inboxsmsbody;
    public  ToastMessageTask(){
        this.inboxsmsdate=InboxSmsDate;
        this.inboxsmsbody=InboxSmsBody;
        this.inboxsmsfrom=InboxSmsFrom;
    }
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        inbox(inboxsmsdate, inboxsmsbody,inboxsmsfrom);
        return null;
    }
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);
    }
}
```

This is a my C# Web service:

```
[WebMethod]
public string inbox(string from, string body, string date)
{
    string connString = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DB_9C047C_deneme2012"].ConnectionString;
    using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connString))
    {
        connection.Open();
        using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand())
        {
            command.Connection = connection;
            command.CommandText = "INSERT INTO Table_1([FROM],BODY,DATE)VALUES(@FROM,@BODY,@DATE)";
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FROM", from);
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@BODY", body);
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DATE", date);
            // SqlCeDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();
            command.ExecuteNonQuery();
            return "true";
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Post your LogCat please.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is a Null Pointer Exception, and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-null-pointer-exception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: The web service is unrelated to the problem. I suspect some string value you're pulling from the SMS content provider is null.

Answer (score 0):

```
private void inbox(String from, String body,String date) {
    SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE3, METHOD_NAME3);
    PropertyInfo DateInfo = new PropertyInfo();
    DateInfo.setName("from");
    DateInfo.setValue(from);
    PropertyInfo BodyInfo = new PropertyInfo();
    BodyInfo.setName("body");
    BodyInfo.setValue(body);
    PropertyInfo FromInfo = new PropertyInfo();
    BodyInfo.setName("date");                        <------------------ error
    BodyInfo.setValue(date);                              <----------------error
    request.addProperty(FromInfo);
    request.addProperty(BodyInfo);
    request.addProperty(DateInfo);
```

Comment: file:///C:/Users/Gokhan/Desktop/Ekran%20Al%C4%B1nt%C4%B1s%C4%B1.PNG